# Retrieving nested relationships in Eloquent?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have three models:

1. Paint
2. Car
3. Make

Paint:

```
{
    "id" : 1,
    "stuff" : "...",
    "car_id" : "4"
}
```

Car:

```
{
    "id" : 4,
    "other_stuff" : "...",
    "make_id" : "7",
}
```

Make:

```
{
    "id" : 7,
    "make_name" : "Toyota"
}
```

When I want to be able to get the following result without manually calling the Make model on it's own:

```
// single Eloquent query to return: 
    {
        "id" : 1,
        "stuff" : "...",
        "car_id" : "4",
        "car" :     {
            "id" : 4,
            "other_stuff" : "...",
            "make_id" : "7",
            "make" :     {
                "id" : 7,
                "make_name" : "Toyota"
            }
        }
    }
```

Single nesting is fine, as you can use Paint::with('car'). Car model has Car::with('car'), but I don't know how to combine the two.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [nested eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading):

```
Paint::with('car.make')->get();
```